# GoogleSignInComponent NgBuild Prod throwing error

Tags: angular, google-signin

I am getting this error when i am running `ng build --prod` but not when `ng build --prod --aot=false`

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'GoogleSignInComponent in .../node_modules/angular-google-signin/index.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModule in ..proj1/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'proj/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I am not sure how can I solve this issue.

The package I am using is `"angular-google-signin": "^0.1.5"`

Any lead will be helpful.

Is there a way, I can only set aot=false for this component. Because due to this component, I have a huge - vendor file that takes ages to load.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [open issues](https://github.com/miltador/angular-google-signin/issues) on Github, it looks like structure of that library has not been updated to be compatible with recent versions of Angular. Specifically, the library doesn't export an `NgModule` that you can import into your app. I would recommend either keeping an eye on a relevant issue on Github (such as [this one](https://github.com/miltador/angular-google-signin/issues/22)) or finding/creating an alternative. I wouldn't have high hopes that the problems with that library will be fixed as it does not seem to be being actively maintained. Maybe you could release your own version using this one as a basis!

Comment: Is there any way, I could ignore "aot" for GoogleSignInComponent?

Comment: @User1911 No, there is no way to perform AOT for some components and not others as far as I know.